# Is it possible to define my own type of Switch statement?

Tags: javascript, raphael

While creating the logic to keep a moving square within bounds of a squared spiral, I ended up with 4 chunks of code that were essentially the same, except for some key variable names and operator instructions.

The idea would be to have the compiler do a copy and paste of the template - in this case 4 times.

And then replace Dollar Sign Values in the template: area - $0, $1, $2 etc - with the data found in the $cases group.

You can see the four chunks of code expanded out, at the bottom of http://jsbin.com/AJemixiT/13/edit .

---

I realize what I want to create is not a function but something that behaves like an "If" or "Switch".  Is it even possible to create your own one of these?

Is this macro programming?

Is this something that would be better tackled by creating a scripting language?

I am wet behind the ears, so any help to get started on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
function switchTemplate(i)
{
    cases:{
         //An Array to correspond with $values below
         (0,x,y,+,>=,+,1),
         (1,y,x,+,>=,-,2),
         (2,x,y,-,<=,-,3),
         (3,y,x,-,<=,+,0)
         };

    template:
    switch (enemy_array[i].data('direction'))
    {
        case $0:  
            if ( (enemy_array[i].attr('$1') $3 enemy_speed) $4 gb_$1_pos_corners[enemy_array[i].data('approaching_corner')] ) 
            {            
                distance_moved = gb_$1_pos_corners[enemy_array[i].data('approaching_corner')] - enemy_array[i].attr('$1');
                enemy_array[i].attr({ 
                                   $1: gb_$1_pos_corners[enemy_array[i].data('approaching_corner')],
                                   $2: enemy_array[i].attr('$2') $5 (enemy_speed - distance_moved)
                                   });
                enemy_array[i].data('direction',$6);
                enemy_array[i].data('approaching_corner',enemy_array[i].data('approaching_corner') + 1);
            }
            else 
            { 
                enemy_array[i].attr({ $1: enemy_array[i].attr('$1') + enemy_speed });
            }
            break;  
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < num_of_enemies_spawned; i++) {
    switchTemplate(i);
}
```

If anyone can think of a better title; please go ahead and change it.

Comment: Yes, what you're trying to do would be the sort of thing Lisp programmers do with macros.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: @Andrea I would like to restructure a bunch of repetitive blocks of code into one block that serves as the template and another that describes the differences.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you feel you need to use a template. You already pretty much have an object. Can't you just create an object with the data, almost like you have already, and pull out the respective data out of the object and just have one copy of the code ? You may need to create a separate func or something for the operator.